# Find percentage exceedances by group in R?

Tags: r

I've got a data set with some missing values and I want to find percentage exceedances over 500,200, median and 95th percentile of Ecoli for each group?

```
Site    Ecoli
A   234
A   450
A   500
A   1096
A   295
A   4567
A   2344
A   234
A   450
B   500
B   1096
B   295
B   4567
B   2344
B   
B   
B   
B
```

I started with this codes

```
table=dat %>% group_by(Site) %>% mutate(E.Coli>500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'Site', we can use `mean` on a logical condition to convert it to percentages.  If the intention is to create columns, use `mutate` instead of `summarise` after the `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
     group_by(Site) %>%
     summarise(PercExeedover500 = 100 *mean(E.Coli > 500, na.rm = TRUE),
               PercExeedover200 = 100 *mean(E.Coli > 200, na.rm = TRUE),
                Quantile95th = quantile(Ecoli, prob = .95, na.rm = TRUE))
```